# Android XML Pull Parsing while loop not working

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I have some XML as seen below

```
<question id="0">
  <text>
    Who is the first President of the United States of America?
  </text>
  <image>
    http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Gilbert_Stuart_Williamstown_Portrait_of_George_Washington.jpg
  </image>
  <choices>
    <choice answer="true">George Washington</choice>
    <choice>Thomas Jefferson</choice>
    <choice>James Monroe</choice>
    <choice>John Adams</choice>
  </choices>
</question>
```

And I am trying to parse it into some objects. Currently, I have a while loop that when the parser checks `if` `"choices"` is the current tag, then it goes in and starts the while loop to get all the choice tags and make objects out of them.

`QuestionUtil`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;
import android.util.Log;

public class QuestionUtil {

static ArrayList<Question> parseQuestions(InputStream xmlIn) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

    XmlPullParser parser = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();
    parser.setInput(xmlIn, "UTF-8");

    Question question = null;
    ArrayList<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<Question>();
    Choices choices = null;
    ArrayList<Choices> choiceList = new ArrayList<Choices>();

    int event = parser.getEventType();

    while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

        switch (event) {
        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

            if(parser.getName().equals("question")) {

                question = new Question();

                try {
                    question.setId(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "id"));
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException ex) { }

            }

            else if (parser.getName().equals("text")) {
                question.setText(parser.nextText());
            }

            else if (parser.getName().equals("image")) {
                question.setImage(parser.nextText());
            }

            else if (parser.getName().equals("choices")) {

                boolean isCorrect;
                String answer;
                parser.next();

/**** (BELOW) THIS PART IS NOT WORKING PROPERLY ****/
                // parser.getName().equals("choice")
                while ("choice".equals(parser.getName())) {

                    if (parser.getAttributeValue(null, "answer") != null) {
                        isCorrect = true;
                        answer = parser.nextText();
                        choices = new Choices(isCorrect, answer);
                    }
                    else {
                        isCorrect = false;
                        answer = parser.nextText();
                        choices = new Choices(isCorrect, answer);
                    }

                    choiceList.add(choices);
                    parser.next();

                    // Testing purposes
                    Log.d("demo", answer + " " + isCorrect);

                }
/**** (ABOVE) THIS PART IS NOT WORKING PROPERLY ****/

                question.setChoices(choiceList);

            } // END Choices Parsing

            break;

        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

            if (parser.getName().equals("question")) {
                questionList.add(question);
                question = null;
            }

            break;

        default:
            break;

        } // END Switch

        event = parser.next();

    } // END While loop

    return questionList;

}

}
```

Can anyone help me figure out why it's not working? As soon as I have an `if` statement to check for the `"choices"` tag, I go ahead and `parser.next()` to go to the next line, which should be `"choice"`. There is not always four choices, there could be more or less, that's why I need to be able to loop through it.

Comment: don't you need a `case XmlPullParser.START_TAG` in your loop over the "choice" items?

Comment: Like a nested `case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:` you mean? I guess that's possible, I'll research it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the fact that you omit the start and the end of the tag is the issue. 
Maybe this will work:

```
 while ("choice".equals(parser.getName())) {
    if (parser.getEventType()==XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        if (parser.getAttributeValue(null, "answer") != null) {
            isCorrect = true;
            answer = parser.nextText();
            choices = new Choices(isCorrect, answer);
        } else {
            isCorrect = false;
            answer = parser.nextText();
            choices = new Choices(isCorrect, answer);
        }
        choiceList.add(choices);
    }
    parser.next();
    // Testing purposes
    Log.d("demo", answer + " " + isCorrect);
}
```

Comment: I think that it will still iterate over the end tag of `choices` because it's in a big while loop. But I did try this in my code and it still, for some reason, does not access the loop period, or I'd have log info via the `Log.d`.

Answer (score 0):

I just avoided looking for the `"choices"` tag all together and found the `"choice"` tag like all the others. To make the logic work, I waited to add the choicesList to the question object till within the next case for the `END_TAG` for the original tag, which is question.

```
else if (parser.getName().equals("choice")) {

                boolean isCorrect;
                String answer;

                if (parser.getAttributeValue(null, "answer") != null) {
                    isCorrect = true;
                    answer = parser.nextText();
                    choices = new Choices(isCorrect, answer);
                }
                else {
                    isCorrect = false;
                    answer = parser.nextText();
                    choices = new Choices(isCorrect, answer);
                }

                choiceList.add(choices);

            } // END Choices Parsing
```

And the next case:

```
case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

            if (parser.getName().equals("question")) {

                // Testing purposes
                Log.d("demo", ">>>" + choiceList.toString());
                question.setChoices(choiceList);
                questionList.add(question);
                question = null;
                choices = null;
                choiceList.clear();

            }

            break;
```

But for some reason the choicesList doesn't want to be added to the question object. Later, when I return a single object, I do not get a list of the questions. I'm sure this is easily fixed.